# Hide div in case one inner div is empty Jquery or CSS3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have some data to display in different divs with the same class name...in which each div has further two divs.

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">Abc</div>
    <div class="div3"><?php echo $row['SOME VALUE']; ?></div>
</div>

<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">Bcd</div>
    <div class="div3"><?php echo $row['SOME VALUE']; ?></div>
</div>

<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">Cde</div>
    <div class="div3"><?php echo $row['SOME VALUE']; ?></div>
</div>

<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">def</div>
    <div class="div3"><?php echo $row['SOME VALUE']; ?></div>
</div>
```

I want to remove "div1" that contains empty "div3". Still i am using if statement repeatedly for every div block to check if "div3" is not empty then show "div1".

```
<?php 

    if(($rown['SOME VALUE'])!=''{
?>

<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">Bcd</div>
    <div class="div3"><?php echo $row['SOME VALUE']; ?></div>
</div>

<?php

}

?>
```

Is it possible to write a Jquery code or CSS3 code once to remove that "div1" which contains empty "div3".

Comment: `if ($(".div3").text() == "")`

Comment: @u_mulder I will have to write it about 35 times as i have about 35 "div1" that contains "div2" and "div3".... Is it possible to write once for all 35 divs... ???

Comment: It you think so then your understanding of jquery is very low.

Comment: Why not just add a condition to the php code that creates it so that it is not even created in the first place? `if(($rown['SOME VALUE']!='')&&($row['SOME VALUE']!='')){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter all `.div3` divs with `each` and remove ones that have empty text:

```
$(".div3").each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).text() == "") { 
        $(el).parent().remove();  
    }

    // variant with trimming
    if ($.trim( $(el).text() ) == "") { 
        $(el).parent().remove();  
    }

});
```

[Simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7pta1kv/).

Comment: Its working for me...But it doesn't hide that "div1" that contain just empty spaces in "div3".